# Bundle Install | rdkafka 0.8.1 ERROR: Version string is empty

Tags: bundler, librdkafka

I am running `bundle install` and encountering this error:

```
Installing rdkafka 0.8.1 with native extensions
ERROR:  Error installing rdkafka:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

checking for strlcpy (by compile)... ok
checking for strerror_r (by compile)... ok
checking for pthread_setname_gnu (by compile)... failed (disable)
checking for pthread_setname_darwin (by compile)... ok
checking for nm (by env NM)... ok (cached)
checking for getrusage (by compile)... ok

###########################################################
###                  Configure failed                   ###
###########################################################
### Accumulated failures:                               ###
###########################################################
 parseversion ()
    module: parseversion
    action: fail
    reason:
Version string is empty
```

Even if I run `gem install rdkafka -v '0.8.1' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` it will still give the same error. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you already tried to upgrade to the latest version 0.9.0? https://rubygems.org/gems/rdkafka/versions/0.9.0

Comment: Not yet and I specifically need version 0.8.1. Actually, sometimes it works but when I restarted my machine it goes back to that error.

Comment: So it seems that you're talking about your development machine. Am I right? How do you manage your ruby version, do you use version-manager like rvm oder asdf? Which ruby version do actually use?